# Does the http load balancer work for any Port?

Tags: tls, google-cloud-platform

I have a Python server on my VM in Google cloud platform. I was wondering if I add an https load balancer to this, is my Python Socket server also secured with that TLS handstand? Or does this only count for port 80 and 443?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your application is not HTTP, an HTTP loadbalancer will not work. GCP HTTP loadbalancer (or other HTTP loadbalancers) work at the protocol level, so if your application doesn't do HTTP, they won't work.

You might use another loadbalancer application, such as [External SSL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl), or roll your own using Nginx [ngx_stream_ssl_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_ssl_module.html) or some other proxy. Anything that supports raw TCP should work.

However, most commonly this is solved by adding SSL support to your application. This can be done with the [ssl](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html) Python module. Be careful though. Security engineering is hard, and it's easy to make implementation mistakes, even when using existing libraries.

Obviously, in either scenario you would have to make sure your client application also supports TLS.